WPS not running on MikroTik AP running RouterOS
I have a MikroTik cAP ac, on which I have configured a few virtual wireless interfaces in addition to the two physical ones.
The web interface shows the WPS Accept button only for the master interfaces (the physical ones), not for the virtual ones – which seems to be a bug.
Both the master interfaces and some of the virtual ones have WPS enabled (virtual push button only).
When I now try to accept a WPS client on a virtual network by entering
/interface wireless wps-push-button wlan2_virtual

I get:
failure: WPS not running

Same when I try the master interface (wlan2). When I try clicking WPS Accept in the master interface config in WebFig, I get the same error message.
Very sporadically this has worked (for the virtual wireless network, using the command line) and I have been able to connect a device, but this is far from reliable. Nothing in the log provides a clue – no entries indicating WPS started or stopped, or that pushing the button failed because WPS is not running. The only thing I see is if the button press is successful and when the button resets after 2 minutes; in the rare cases where I was able to register a device, I saw some entries related to that.
Where do I see if WPS is running, where can I start it, what could be preventing it from running, and what can I do about that?

Don't know much about MikroTik specifically, but WPS is totally insecure.  Maybe their firmware is doing something (like limiting how long it runs for) to try and mitigate the security issue?

As I understand WPS, the vulnerabilities arise only during association (someone pressing the button). Just because a device theoretically supports WPS wouldn’t make it exploitable as long as the button is protected – e.g. not a physical button but a virtual one in an admin console, protected with at least a password (if an attacker gets past that, you have bigger things to worry about than WPS vulnerabilities).

I'm not an expert here, but I'm pretty sure your understanding is not quite right - WPS has a system generated 8 digit code that can be used to authenticate without pressing the WPS button. (https://sviehb.wordpress.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/viehboeck_wps.pdf goes into some depth about the flawed design of WPS)

I see what you mean – I really should have written WPS PBC specifically (afaik RouterOS doesn’t even support WPS with PIN). PBC is only active from the moment the button is pressed until authentication succeeds or times out after 2 minutes (see p. 3 of the above paper). That could be implemented by starting WPS only upon pressing the button, and stopping it upon success/timeout. Randomly disabling the button doesn’t really make sense in that scenario, so I doubt this was done on purpose. It looks more like a bug, or an error in my configuration.
